# Creating test cases in Jest for render

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following code to test in React

```
render() {
    if (this.state.isDone) {
      return(...)
    } else {
      return(...)
    }
}
```

In the code above, I need to test both conditions. However, when running the below test, one branch is getting tested.

```
it('renderTest', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<CheckState />);
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
});
```

In the above code, only the else part gets covered in the test. The parameter in this is assigned during the process of the component. Is it possible for me to test the same by passing a parameter?

Comment: in which case component's `state.isDone` is changed? after button is clicked? if some `props` has been changed? after some child triggered prop callback?

Comment: @skyboyer - yes, some properties are changed after button is clicked, along with other operations.

Comment: so simulate clicking and validate if it affects component as you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setState](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setState.html) method of `enzyme` to change your component state. Below solution only for testing the `render` method independently without `simulate` an event.

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';

interface ICheckStateState {
  isDone: boolean;
}

export class CheckState extends React.Component<{}, ICheckStateState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isDone: false
    };
  }

  public render() {
    if (this.state.isDone) {
      return <div>Done</div>;
    } else {
      return <div>Not Done</div>;
    }
  }
}
```

`index.spec.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, ShallowWrapper } from 'enzyme';
import { CheckState } from './';

describe('CheckState', () => {
  describe('#render', () => {
    let wrapper: ShallowWrapper;
    beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = shallow(<CheckState></CheckState>);
    });
    it('should render correctly', () => {
      expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
      expect(wrapper.text()).toBe('Not Done');
      wrapper.setState({ isDone: true });
      expect(wrapper.text()).toBe('Done');
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58059957/index.spec.tsx
  CheckState
    #render
      ✓ should render correctly (8ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.819s, estimated 6s
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can do that if we modify the state inside the component to accommodate a specific value from `props` and if nothing is passed from prop then give a default value, something like this -:

```
class CheckState extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        this.state = {
            isDone: props.isDone || false
        };
    }
.......
```

Also test case needs to be something like this -:

```
it('renderTest', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<CheckState />);
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
    const wrapper = shallow(<CheckState isDone={true}/>);
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);

});
```